# Event Store subscription service to MongoDB

Tags: c#, neventstore, eventstoredb

I was wondering if it was possible to create a subscription service to `Mongo` via `Get Event Store`? Perhaps I have phrased this incorrectly but let me explain. I currently have a process which writes events to a `Mongo Database` using `NEventStore`. What I would like to do is have a subscription service which subscribes to a `Stream` in `Mongo`.

Not been able to find anything on the interweb about this in particular however is this possible? My question in a nutshell perhaps is can you mix and match the two together or in order to do this I must write my events to `eventstore` as opposed to `Mongo`? Perhaps, I am going about this wrong and there is an alternative?

I can see my event being written however it fails to trigger `EventAppeared`. All of this is being done locally on my machine for now.

I have tried creating a stripped down app which does this:

1. Create a subscription using the following

   ```
       using (var connection = EventStoreConnection.Create(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1113)))
       {
           connection.SubscribeToStreamAsync(@"mongodb://localhost:27017/Test", false, EventAppeared, SubscriptionDropped);

           var repository = new NEventStoreRepository();
           repository.Write(new SomethingHasHappened("Hello"));

           Console.ReadLine();
       }

   private static void SubscriptionDropped(EventStoreSubscription arg1, SubscriptionDropReason arg2, Exception arg3)
   {
   }

   private static void EventAppeared(EventStoreSubscription arg1, ResolvedEvent arg2)
   {
   }
   ```
2. I write an event to my mongo database via NEventStore

   ```
   public void Write(object @event)
   {
       var id = Guid.NewGuid();

       using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
       {
           using (var store = WireupEventStore())
           {
               using (var stream = store.OpenStream(id.ToString(), 0, int.MaxValue))
               {
                   stream.Add(new EventMessage { Body = @event });
                   stream.CommitChanges(Guid.NewGuid());
                   scope.Complete();
               }
           }
       }

       Console.ReadKey();
   }

   private static IStoreEvents WireupEventStore()
   {
       return Wireup
           .Init()
           .LogToOutputWindow()
           .UsingMongoPersistence("NEventStore.MongoDB", new DocumentObjectSerializer())
           .InitializeStorageEngine()
           .UsingJsonSerialization()
           .Build();
   }
   ```

Comment: Are you talking about GetEventStore ?

Comment: Apologies, yes I am.

Comment: You've got your mongodb connection as the name of your event stream in GetEventStore. Is this intentional? Is your stream actually called "mongodb://localhost:27017/Test"?

Comment: @tomliversidge, no its not called that however it is the stream that is being written to by another process. Perhaps I have misunderstood the documentation but I thought it was the stream that I want to monitor?

Comment: GetEventStore and MongoDb have no built-in way of communicating with each other. You're saving to MongoDb but subscribing to EventStore

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal flow of events for this would be as follows:

(given everything is installed and running...)

1. Register a subscriber to a stream in GetEventStore in your
   application code
2. Save events to the stream
3. The events appear in your subscriber

I think you are either confusing the flow of things or trying to do something totally unsupported (like having MongoDb subscriber to GetEventStore). What I *think* your code is doing is:

1. Setting up NEventStore to save to MongoDb
2. Subscribing to a stream in GetEventStore called "mongodb://localhost:27017/Test"
3. Saving an event to MongoDb

As far as I can see, you're never saving any events to GetEventStore, hence why nothing ever appears in the EventAppeared method. You're saving to MongoDb.

[UPDATE]

> I want to subscribe to a Mongodb stream and populate GetEventStore which I believe isn't possible from what I gather from your answer.

MongoDb doesn't have streams, it has collections - it is a document database. Streams are a concept in GetEventStore. However, it looks like NEventStore allows you to hook up a message dispatcher which presumably means you can register handlers to listen to events. In these handlers, you can then save to GetEventStore.

Comment: I believe you have answered my question. However, I want to subscribe to a Mongodb stream and populate GetEventStore which I believe isn't possible from what I gather from your answer..

Comment: you'd have to hook into whatever mechanism NEventStore uses to allow you to subscribe to events, then inside your handler, save to EventStore: https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore-Example/blob/master/NEventStore.Example/MainProgram.cs#L55.

Comment: Cheers for the help appreciate it. It felt what I was doing was wrong  but wanted to confirm this. I have another approach which I know will work (basically what you mentioned in the answer)